# Can't use Flex in new Angular-8 application

Tags: angular, flexbox, angular-material

When I use Flex in my new Angular 8 app, I face this Error message.

ERROR

> Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[DefaultLayoutDirective -> StyleUtils]:
>   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[DefaultLayoutDirective -> StyleUtils]:
>   NullInjectorError: No provider for StyleUtils!

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.0.0-rc.8",
    "@angular/common": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^9.0.0-beta.28",
    "@angular/forms": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "8.0.0",
    "core-js": "2.6.9",
    "rxjs": "6.5.2",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "0.9.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.10.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.0.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not a flex issue. It seems that you haven't provided in the module `StyleUtils`.

Comment: is it related to flex or to the flex layout library?

Comment: @JacopoSciampi Can you please check this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-527ggu?file=package.json

Comment: @GérômeGrignon yes I think. Cause, if I don't use Flex then the error disappears

Comment: Have a look here, it's an issue of the beta version you're using: https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/1186

Answer (score 2):

Change this line of dependency in your package.json:

```
"@angular/flex-layout": "8.0.0",
```

and import this module into your `app.module.ts`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    FlexLayoutModule
  ],
})
```

The most recent iteration of the package could be buggy, therefore I would recommend to use an older stable version instead of the beta version. It should also reflect the version number of the other @angular packages to ensure compatibility.

Comment: In an applicacion with ng-cli 8 I used     "@angular/flex-layout": "^7.0.0-beta.23",
and works very well

Comment: There is always a percentage of compatibility. Not every major version changes all interfaces. It could work, but is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and could only solve it by adding the providers to the module

```
import { ɵMatchMedia, BreakPointRegistry, PrintHook } from '@angular/flex-layout/core';                
import { FlexLayoutModule, StyleUtils, StylesheetMap, LayoutStyleBuilder, MediaMarshaller, LayoutAlignStyleBuilder, FlexStyleBuilder } from '@angular/flex-layout';


 providers:[
    PrintHook,
    StyleUtils, 
    StyleSheet,
    StylesheetMap, 
    LayoutAlignStyleBuilder,
    LayoutStyleBuilder,
    FlexStyleBuilder,
    MediaMarshaller,
    ɵMatchMedia,
    BreakPointRegistry],
```

Comment: We don't need StyleSheet, Rest others are needed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above solution but didn't work.
I did the following which worked for me

```
ng update --next @angular/cli --force
npm install typescript@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have your @angular/flex version under the same version or similar to your @angular/cli version. You can check them both in package.json.

```
"dependencies": 
{
"@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.27",
.....
"devDependencies": 
{
"@angular/cli": "~8.0.6",
```

To upgrade or downgrade you @angular/version, you just remove the curent version line in the package.json and run this command to install the one that you want
`npm i @angular/flex-layout@the_version_you_want`

ex: `npm i @angular/flex-layout@8.0.0-beta.27`

And that should resolve your problem...